# Scala Reflection: how to get class given String name of the class

Tags: scala, reflection

I read a few posts on Scala Reflection.
e.g.
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

In my case, I want to see if given class name can be instantiated.
e.g. org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.SqlLexical

I cannot directly use SqlLexical (defined in Spark 1.6) because the runtime may be Spark 2.0

How can I retrieve the class given the String classname ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's help:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader
import scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader

scala> ScalaClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader).tryToLoadClass("scala.Option")
res0: Option[Class[Nothing]] = Some(class scala.Option)

scala> ScalaClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader).create("scala.UninitializedError")
res1: AnyRef = scala.UninitializedError: uninitialized value
```

Backwardly compatibly:

```
$ scala210
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_95).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader
import scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader

scala> ScalaClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader).create("scala.UninitializedError")
res0: AnyRef = scala.UninitializedError: uninitialized value

scala> 

$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader
import scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader

scala> ScalaClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader).create("scala.UninitializedError")
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res0: AnyRef = scala.UninitializedError: uninitialized value
```

Comment: scala> import scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader
  <console>:7: error: object ScalaClassLoader is not a member of package scala.reflect.internal.util
       import scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader
              ^

Comment: The solution I am looking for has to work for both Scala 2.10 and 2.11

Comment: They moved classes around because of how the reflection library is structured. Such is history, such is FOSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly scala solution, but you can try to load it with [ClassLoader.loadClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)) and then get constructors and call them to an instance.